# How to obtain values for variabe

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to insert path (or value) of images in to variable var objJson. I insert, but images are not shown. Instead that is shown just images names

[image: you can see here]

Please help figure that. This part code I use for images pagination.

```
var current_page = 1;
var records_per_page = 4;

var objJson = [
{ adName: "image1.jpg"},
{ adName: "image2.jpg"},
{ adName: "image3.jpg"},
{ adName: "image4.jpg"},
{ adName: "AdName 5"},
{ adName: "AdName 6"},
{ adName: "AdName 7"},
{ adName: "AdName 8"},
{ adName: "AdName 9"},
{ adName: "AdName 10"}
];
```

Comment: can we see how you implement the images?

Comment: show us how you implemented the images?

Comment: Images are in root directory. And  I just insert images names into variable.

Comment: Variable is in seperate JS file. These images are shown in html.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution: You need to make use of img tag to show images in the html.

`<img tag src="/path of the image">`

If you are using jquery, you can insert the img tags dynamically, using the following code.

```
$('#yourtargetDiv').prepend('<img src="image_path_variable_here" />')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Instead div '#yourtargetDiv' can be a variable, which is referenced to div?

Comment: As I understand here can be path or variable '<img src="image_path_variable_here" />'